# How to have a canvas script in head?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have written some code that just should show me a circle (1.5 * pi).

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Canvas Experiments</title>

    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        function drawCircle() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 1.5 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        window.addEventListener("load", drawCircle);
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks to Alexander Nied, I learned that I could just move  to . But is there another solution? I want script to be part of head.

Comment: Try moving your `<script>` block to the bottom of the `<body>`.  My hunch is it is looking for those things before they exist in the DOM.  I'd make a snippet but it seems to be down...

Comment: @AlexanderNied thank you. It works. But is there a method to keep it in the head section?

Comment: You could try making it a named `function` and then assigning it to either [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) or [`window.DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)... I'd do some more research before using those at my word, though-- I don't exactly recall  off the top of my head what's considered the best practice these days for considering "DOM Ready` in vanilla JS...

Comment: you are already calling function on window load event, so just move **var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");** lines in your function **drawCircle**

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra - good catch, Alpesh.